# How to run python script on atom using anaconda python?

Tags: python

I was trying to move from using the Spyder IDE that comes with Anaconda3 to using Atom text editor however after downloading the "scprit" package I tried running one of the files done in class which were done using Spyder I got this

"Python was not found but can be installed from the Microsoft Store: [https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640"](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?linkID=2082640%22)

I then attempted to look for a tutorial on how to run my files using Atom with anaconda python interpreter at some point in the video we used the command 'where python' on anaconda3 prompt and I got this:

C:\Users\UserName\anaconda3\python.exe
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

apparently I do have python? even the one in the Microsoft store and anaconda3? I don't understand this.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why migrate from Spyder (a dedicated Python IDE) to a glorified text editor?

Comment: What is the output when you try python command on Command prompt